# wp-admin has gone after put a .htaccess rule

Tags: wordpress

I had to change something in my .htaccess file in order to put friendly urls in a section of my webpage, but the change was so little, as you can see in my .htaccess file that you can see below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^info-destinos/([a-z-]*)$ info-destinos/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The only line that I add was the fourth line, and when I updated this file in my server, since then my wordpress admin panel crashed and it never works again, only send me the following errors when I try to access to it:

- When I use: www.parquedelcafe.travel/wp-admin, sends me:

[image]
- And when I use simply https://www.parquedelcafe.travel/wp-login.php, sends me:

[image]

I already searched for a solution through the web but nothing works, I applied all the solutions that are out there:

- Deactivate the plugins folder
- Change the .htaccess to the default code
- Add the following lines to the wp-config.php:

```php
define('WP_HOME','https://www.parquedelcafe.travel');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.parquedelcafe.travel');
```

And nothing works! :(, please help me I was stuck in this issue for four days. In advance I will appreciate any help

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache, an incognito window or a different browser?

Comment: Yes I already prove that way and nothing happened, didn't work

Comment: Have you tried completely removing your htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

<< You have FTP or Cpanel

1. visit root folder just change name of .htaccess
2. Rename plugin folder
3. And try to open  https://www.parquedelcafe.travel/wp-login.php
4. check error.log file it has generate at root folder itself.
5. enable debug mode in wp-config.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I said I already made this way